# How to prove an inifnite sum

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^n}{n!}=e^{-2}$$

I do know that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^{x}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$$

But I never had a real proof of it and is there an other way to prove the infinite sum above?

Comment: What is your _definition_ of $e^x$?

Comment: I know the definition, but the proof of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$$ is basicly what I need.

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Equivalence_of_the_characterizations) help?

Comment: The problem is that I want to have a prove of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$$ or to prove it in a different way. It is easy to show it when you use those formulas, but what if you dont know them or you can't use them. There should still be a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's prove that series.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$
From the binomial theorem we have

$$
\begin{align}
\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n & = 1 + x + \frac{n(n-1)}{2!n^2}x^2 + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3! n^3}x^3 + \cdots
\\\\
& = \frac{x^0}{0!} + \frac{x^1}{1!} + \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\frac{x^2}{2!} + \left(\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{n^2}\right)\frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots 
\end{align}
$$

Now as $n\to \infty$ each term in the brackets is $1$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}  \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right) = 1$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}  \left(\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{n^2}\right) = 1$$

Et cetera.

What remains is

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n & = \frac{x^0}{0!} + \frac{x^1}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots
\\\\
& = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}
\\\\
& = e^x
\end{align}
$$

Thence use $x = -2$ and make a backwards calculation, et voilà.

Answer (score 0):

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^n}{n!}=e^{-2}$$

you know that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^{x}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$$

Set $x=-2$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^n}{n!}=e^{-2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{-2}{n})^n$$

---

The proof from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Equivalence_of_the_characterizations):

Let 
$x\geq0$ 
be a fixed non-negative real number. Define

$s_n = \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!},\ t_n=\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$

By the [binomial theorem](https://www.google.co.il/search?hl=en&q=binomial+theorem&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=iA--VuH7HYevygPo-534Bg),

\begin{align}
t_n & =\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}\frac{x^k}{n^k}=1+x+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-(k-1))x^k}{k!\,n^k} \\[8pt]
& = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{x^3}{3!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)+\cdots \\[8pt]
& {}\qquad \cdots +\frac{x^n}{n!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\le s_n
\end{align}